# Trying to reuse code across multiple Flask servers, stuck on importing with errors "ModuleNotFoundError" or "ImportError"

Tags: python

My goal is to import code into three separate Flask servers. It's not going well. I am on `python 3.10.4`. I have read perhaps 10 different posts that say things like "put a `__init__.py` file in your folders" which I have done.

For context I'm not exactly new to Python but I've never learned the importing/module system properly.

I have three Flask servers that run scraping operations on different (but similar) websites. I need them to be separate for various reasons. Anyway, all three need to run the same procedure of getting an IP for a proxy from my proxy provider. For this I have some code:

```
# we don't need the details here so I snip it to save space

def get_proxy_ip(choice):
    r = requests.get(download_list, headers={"Authorization": "Token " + token})
    selected_proxy_ip = r.json()["results"][choice]["proxy_address"]
    selected_proxy_port = r.json()["results"][choice]["port"]
    print(selected_proxy_ip)
    return selected_proxy_ip, selected_proxy_port
```

I want to use this function across all 3 of my Flask servers. Here are some various ways I've tried to import the code into one of the Flask servers:

`scrapers/rentCanada/app.py`

```
import requests
from flask import Flask, request, make_response
print("cats")
app = Flask(__name__)
print(__name__, __package__)
# from ..shared.ipgetter import get_proxy_ip
# from ..shared.checker import check_public_ip
# from scrapers.shared.ipgetter import get_proxy_ip
# from scrapers.shared.checker import check_public_ip
import shared.ipgetter as ipgetter
import shared.checker as checker
```

None of them work.
`import shared.ipgetter as ipgetter` yields:

```
cats
__main__ None
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/rlm/Code/canadaAps/scrapers/rentCanada/app.py", line 10, in <module>
    import shared.ipgetter as ipgetter
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'shared'
```

`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'scrapers'` yields: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'scrapers'`

`from ..shared.ipgetter import get_proxy_ip` yields: `ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package`

At this point you need to see my folder structure.

```
/scrapers
..__init__.py
..setup.py
../rentCanada
.....__init__.py
.....app.py
../rentFaster
.....__init__.py
.....app.py
../rentSeeker
.....__init__.py
.....app.py
../shared
.....__init__.py
.....ipgetter.py
.....checker.py
```

I need to be able to use any of the `app.py` files as entry points.

I also tried `setup.py` with this:

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages
setup(
    name = 'tools',
    packages = find_packages(),
)
```

followed by `python setup.py install` but that didn't make a "tools" import available in `app.py` like I wanted.

As a final note I suspect someone will tell me to use a blueprint. To me those look like a tool I'd use if I was adding a route. I'm not sure they're right for a simple function, but maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: Why not have _one_ flask application, and run three instances with different configurtions? Not only does it bypass your current conundrum, it is the better and simpler solution.

Comment: @alexis Upon further consideration, I'll be rewriting it the way you recommend. It simplifies things, and makes the code more tidy (since I can now wrap it in objects). My original reason was that (a) the code would be different at every step for each of the 3 different APIs I'm scraping, and (b) if one gets ip banned, it can act independently from the others.

But I see now that *running three instances with different configurations* is the superior path.

Comment: Glad to hear you see it that way now. If the code bases have little in common, you can still keep them in separate modules and just load the one you need based on the config. It's easy to set up and manage. (This is still different from having _one_ running instance scraping three websites, which is what you want to avoid.)

Answer (score 0):

My solution for now is to run Flask with `python rentCanada/app.py` from the `/scrapers` folder and use this code

```
import sys
from pathlib import Path
sys.path.append(str(Path(__file__).parent.parent))  # necessary so util folder is available
import requests
from flask import Flask, request, make_response

print("cats")
app = Flask(__name__)
print(__name__, __package__)

from util.ipgetter import get_proxy_ip
from util.checker import check_public_ip
```

So the program appends the `app.py` file folder's parent folder to the path. That makes the `util` folder (which used to be `shared` but had a naming conflict) available within the `app.py` file.